# is there a way to find the greatest number from random numbers?

Tags: python, list, max, min

i am writing a code to find the max and min number from a python list. if i provide numbers in list it is easy to get output, but i want to get output from random numbers, how to do it.

i have tried using max() but it does not work with random numbers

```
import random
list = []
print (len(list))
for i in range(1,10):
    print (random.randint(100,200))
for num in list:
     list = [random]
     print (list)
```

also i have tried using

```
index = list.index(max(list))
print ('index of max is ', index)
```

this works if i provide the numbers, but not with random.

the output of both max and min is same.

Comment: `list` is a reserved word don't use it for a variable name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to populate the list, and later find the minimum and maximum values:

```
import random

lst = []
for i in range(1, 10):
    lst.append(random.randint(100, 200))

print(max(lst))
print(min(lst))
```

Notice that it's more idiomatic to use a list comprehension, as shown in @vurmux's answer.

Answer (score 6):

You are not filling your list with numbers, you are just printing them. Your list is actually empty.

Try this:

```
import random

list_ = [random.randint(100,200) for _ in range(10)]
print(list_)
print(max(list_))
```

P.S. Don't name variables equal to the keywords, like `list`, `dict` etc. It is very bad idea that can lead to various errors.

Answer (score 1):

print (len(list)) //It will always print 0. Because list is empty at this time. You need to populate it with random numbers.

Also it is not a good practice to use Python Keywords as name of lists,sets,variables etc. It could raise errors. You have used list which a constructor for creating lists.

Here's what you need to do:-

```
import random
numlist = []

for i in range(1,10):
     numlist.append(random.randint(100,200))

print(max(numlist))
print(min(numlist))
```

Read about max here :-
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max